# Remove comma if single metafield in Shopify Liquid

Tags: shopify

I'm struggling with remove the comma, when a single author is there for a book.
What I want is
Author1, Author

Below is my code

```
 <a href="/collections/all/{{ product.metafields.text.author_1 | handleize }}">{{ product.metafields.text.author_1 }}</a>

 {% for line_item in line_items %}
 {
 {% unless forloop.last %}
 },
 {% else %}
 }
 {% endunless %}
 {% endfor %}
 <a href="/collections/all/{{ product.metafields.text.author_2 | handleize }}">{{ product.metafields.text.author_2 }}</a>
```

Can you please help me with this

Comment: what is the current output from your code?

Comment: What is the relation of line_items with Authors ? Why you need to loop over line_items to add Comma between Authors ?

Comment: @Onkar It's a book store website, some books have 2 authors for which i have made metafields (author_1) and (author_2). so right now it works when 2 authors, but when a single authoer it shows (authorname,). It shows a comma even when single author. I hope I was clear. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand why this loop through line_items.

This should work (not tested):

```
{{ product.metafields.text.author_1 | strip }}{{ product.metafields.text.author_2 | prepend:', ' }}
```

Comment: I did try this but there's a space between author_1, the output is like Author1 , Author2

Comment: I've edited the answer. All you have to do to manage this is to apply a strip filter on Author1 value .